# problem with iterating over non existing indexes python

Tags: python, loops, woocommerce-rest-api

I have extracted data from woocommerce webshop with api. Part of the top structure is like this:

```
{'id': 12345,
 'attributes': [{'id': 1,
       'name': 'kleur',
       'position': 0,
       'visible': True,
       'variation': False,
       'options': ['blauw']},
      {'id': 2,
       'name': 'maat',
       'position': 1,
       'visible': True,
       'variation': True,
       'options': ['s',
        'm',
        'l']}], 
  ..................
}
```

try to make a list of dicts

```
all_webshop_skus = []   
for item in all_data:
        product= {}
        product = {
                'id':item['id'],
                'sku': item['sku'], 
                'name' : item['name'],
                'date_created': item['date_created'],
                'brands': item['brands'][0]['name'],
                'attributes': item['attributes'][1]['name']
             }
        all_webshop_skus.append(product)
```

iteration has index issues

```
---> 16                 'attributes': item['attributes'][1]['name']
     17              }
     18         all_webshop_skus.append(product)

IndexError: list index out of range
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think because not every item has a second element in the 'attributes' list of dicts. How can I extract 'name'_values from 'attributes' with 'attribute_id'_value = 2?

Comment: What's the reason for `product = {}`? You replace it with a different dictionary on the next line.

Comment: you're right. No need.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the attributes until you find the one you want, and use its name.

```
all_webshop_skus = []   
for item in all_data:
    for attr in item['attributes']:
        if attr['id'] == 2:
            name = attr['name']
            break
    else: # default if not found
        name = ''

    product = {
        'id': item['id'],
        'sku': item['sku'], 
        'name' : item['name'],
        'date_created': item['date_created'],
        'brands': item['brands'][0]['name'],
        'attributes': name
    }
    all_webshop_skus.append(product)
```